# Transforming point using NetTopologySuite

Tags: coordinate-system, nettopologysuite

I'm exploring how we can use NetTopologySuite to address a geoprocessing task. based on some code sample I found, I was able to piece together a sample application that reads a shapefile and checks if a point falls within a polygon. The issue is, my point is in WGS84 but the shapefile is in EPSG:2810. I need to transform the input point to the CRS of the shapefile.

How do I convert a point from WGS to EPSG:2810 using NetTopologySuite 1.13.3?

Here's some of the code I have so far:

```cs
string shpFilename = @"C:\...\polygons.shp";
GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();
var coord = new Coordinate(-90.00, 45.00);
var point = factory.CreatePoint(coord);
```

I should also note that when I manually convert from WGS84 to the projected system and use those converted values, my code works as designed. This confirms this is a matter of transforming the coordinates before attempting to determine if they fall within a polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way of making point-to-point coordinate conversions in NTS is by using the [ProjNet4GeoAPI](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI) library.

Here is a coordinate transformation example taken from the unit tests:

```cs
public void TestTransformListOfCoordinates()
{
    CoordinateSystemFactory csFact = new CoordinateSystemFactory();
    CoordinateTransformationFactory ctFact = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

    ICoordinateSystem utm35ETRS = csFact.CreateFromWkt(
            "PROJCS[\"ETRS89 / ETRS-TM35\",GEOGCS[\"ETRS89\",DATUM[\"D_ETRS_1989\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",27],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]");

    IProjectedCoordinateSystem utm33 = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WGS84_UTM(33, true);

    ICoordinateTransformation trans = ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(utm35ETRS, utm33);

    Coordinate[] points = new Coordinate[]
    {
        new Coordinate(290586.087, 6714000), new Coordinate(290586.392, 6713996.224),
        new Coordinate(290590.133, 6713973.772), new Coordinate(290594.111, 6713957.416),
        new Coordinate(290596.615, 6713943.567), new Coordinate(290596.701, 6713939.485)
    };

    Coordinate[] tpoints = trans.MathTransform.TransformList(points).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        Assert.That(tpoints[i].Equals(trans.MathTransform.Transform(points[i])));
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, using this code does not return the same result as using ESRI.ArcGISRuntime. So either this ProjNet4 library is incorrect or there is a misunderstanding on how to use this code. I was trying to do a NAD83 to WSG84, and https://tagis.dep.wv.gov/convert/ does give me the same result as ESRI, but ProjNet4 does not give me the same result :(

Comment: @jsgoupil Coud be related with this issue? https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/issues/17 It's marked as resolved 21 days ago. Are you ussing the latest build?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, the outcome of this bug is not clear what is the problem. I have opened a bug here: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/issues/51 I am using ProjNET4GeoAPI 1.4.1

Answer (score 5):

The answer works fine with points. But if you do this with polygons with holes it will return points out of order. Then when you turn those points back into a polygon it will complain about LineStrings not closing.

I ended up using the [ProjNet](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI) library to build my transformation and then NetTopologySuite has a utility that handles polygons.

Looks something like this. You can get the WKT projection text from [SpatialReference.org](http://spatialreference.org/). You could easily expand this for all geometry types.

```cs
static GeoAPI.Geometries.IPolygon ProjectGeometry(GeoAPI.Geometries.IPolygon polygeo, string FromWKT, string ToWKT)
{
    var SourceCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(FromWKT);
    var TargetCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(ToWKT);

    var trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(SourceCoordSystem, TargetCoordSystem);

    var poly = NetTopologySuite.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.GeometryTransform.TransformPolygon(polygeo.Factory, polygeo, trans.MathTransform);
    return poly;
}
```

**Update**
The above code doesn't work with the new version of NetTopologySuite. Below is an updated version that works with NetTopologySuite 2.0.0.

```cs
static NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry ProjectGeometry(NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry geom, string FromWKT, string ToWKT)
{
    var SourceCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(FromWKT);
    var TargetCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(ToWKT);

    var trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(SourceCoordSystem, TargetCoordSystem);

    var projGeom = Transform(geom, trans.MathTransform);

    return projGeom;
}

static NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry Transform(NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry geom, MathTransform transform)
{
    geom = geom.Copy();
    geom.Apply(new MTF(transform));
    return geom;
}

sealed class MTF : NetTopologySuite.Geometries.ICoordinateSequenceFilter
{
    private readonly MathTransform _mathTransform;

    public MTF(MathTransform mathTransform) => _mathTransform = mathTransform;

    public bool Done => false;
    public bool GeometryChanged => true;
    public void Filter(NetTopologySuite.Geometries.CoordinateSequence seq, int i)
    {
        double x = seq.GetX(i);
        double y = seq.GetY(i);
        double z = seq.GetZ(i);
        _mathTransform.Transform(ref x, ref y, ref z);
        seq.SetX(i, x);
        seq.SetY(i, y);
        seq.SetZ(i, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this solution, but I get a "type or namespace name 'CoordinateSystems' does not exist in the namespace 'NetTopologySuite'". Has this been removed in the new release?

Comment: @Littlegeek Yes this has been removed from the new version. I'll update with what I'm using now.

Comment: Thank you @DonnyV., but when I try to use the updated code I get "Cannot convert from GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformation.IMathTransform to ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.MathTransform"

Comment: @Littlegeek What line does this happen on? Also you may have a using statement thats GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformation and thats why MathTransform is defaulting to using GeoAPI's version instead of ProjNet.

Comment: It happens at `Transform(geom, trans.MathTransform);`. It happens without any using statements with GeoAPI. Btw. `_mathTransform.Transform(ref x, ref y, ref z)` does not take three input arguments. It should be a `double[]`.

Comment: @Littlegeek Your using a different version of ProjNET. I'm using version 2.0.0

Comment: @Littlegeek I had similar issue because I added the ProjNet4GeoApi instead of ProjNet from nuget...

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same need. I also found an example from the test. They revealed the details. But this approach is not convenient when working with the IGeometry type (IPoint, ILineString, etc).

After some research, I found how to transform geometry in a more convenient way (Thanks to NTS github repository :)

1) we should create transformation:

```cs
ICoordinateTransformation Wgs84ToWebMercator =
        (new CoordinateTransformationFactory())
        .CreateFromCoordinateSystems(GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84, 
                ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator);
```

2) declare filter, which will iterate through geometry sequence and made all work:

```cs
public class CoordinateTransformationFilter : ICoordinateSequenceFilter
{
    private readonly ICoordinateTransformation _transformation;

    public CoordinateTransformationFilter(ICoordinateTransformation transformation)
    {
        _transformation = transformation ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(transformation)} can't be null.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Yes, always true.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Done => true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Automatic call IGeometry.GeometryChanged() method after tranformation.
    /// </summary>
    public bool GeometryChanged => true;

    public void Filter(ICoordinateSequence seq, int i)
    {
        _transformation.MathTransform.Transform(seq);
    }
}
```

3) create filter:

```cs
var transformFilter = new CoordinateTransformationFilter(Wgs84ToWebMercator );
```

4) Profit:

```cs
// Get point from anywhere in WGS84 (aka EPSG:4326)
IPoint srcPoint = ...;
// You can skip it. But your geometry will be changed.
IPoint projectedPoint = srcPoint.Clone() as IPoint;
// Magic happen here. Our point in WebMercator (aka EPSG:3857)
projectedPoint.Apply(transformFilter);
```

**UPDATE 2019-07-09:** this solution for ProjNET4GeoAPI v1.4.1. I assume that it will not work with new version.

Comment: This answer is probably the closest where I needed to get. However, I am not a pro in this, but I don't think the `CoordinateTransformationFilter` is correct. The `Transform` method returns a value, it does not change the `seq`. Also the `Done` should probably be set to `false` to go through all the coordinates. Maybe this code could help: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/blob/b8ff647ae4636b45fadfb5879b679fc36e7340ba/NetTopologySuite/Precision/CoordinatePrecisionReducerFilter.cs

Comment: @jsgoupil This answer is for ProjNET4GeoAPI v1.4.1. And as we can see in [source code](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/blob/v1/master/ProjNet/CoordinateSystems/Transformations/MathTransform.cs) on line 215 and 216 - ICoordinateSequence is changing despite the documentation. But in master there is no such behavior as I can see.

Comment: Wow, I think that's a bug in their code. Because if you look at all the `Transform(ICoordinateSequence coordinateSequence)`, this [one](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/blob/v1/master/ProjNet/CoordinateSystems/Transformations/ConcatenatedTransform.cs#L115) makes a Clone. I was about to open a bug, but it is already [fixed for future version](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/issues/26). Also I really think your Done should be `false` so that if an entry like a `IPolygon` is being passed, all the sequences will be run properly.

Comment: @jsgoupil I will be honest. I do not know what the value of the Done property should be. I found in the source some example that looks like what I need and changed it. Checked that works (at least on Point and LineString) and calmed down.