# Converting lat/long to northing/easting given data from a .prj file

Tags: shapefile, .net, nettopologysuite

I have been given the a file containing a bunch of lat long coordinates along with this information that came from a ".prj" file alongside a ".shp" file:

`GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

I need to convert the lat/long coordinates which I've parsed out of the ".shp" file to northing/easting coordinates, but I don't understand this data - I'm a software engineer with very little knowledge of GIS, and I'm unsure where to start, and as far as I can tell, the above WKT isn't enough to perform the conversion.

I have some other data which is already in northing/easting format, and I need to make sure the two are aligned. I'm using the NetTopologySuite.Proj4Net library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this web-based conversion tool to do the conversion:
https://www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx (paid subscription required for batch conversions...)
or you can do it one coordinate at a time:
https://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx

Also look at this similar question and its answers:
[How do I transform a point using NetTopologySuite?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/165022/171694)

Comment: The problem is the WKT I posted above doesn't parse in NTP, so the conversion obviously fails. I'm assuming the WKT doesn't contain necessary data - or perhaps is incorrectly formatted? I don't really know, do you? The earthpoint site also requires I enter information I don't have - I'm unsure which state plane is being used - I only have the WKT I posted. Does that define a state plane?